# There is a huge speed difference between reading and writing in DRAM, is this normal?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, benchmarking, memory-bandwidth

I want to measure the bandwidth of my DRAM during reading and writing.

Measurement method: repeatedly scan a 128MB array, only accessing the first 4 bytes of each cache line. Reading uses `add eax/ebx, [mem]`, writing uses `mov [mem], eax`.

The expected result: the bandwidth of writing is 1/2 of the bandwidth of reading, because the cache uses a write-back policy.

The actual result: the bandwidth of writing is only 1/20 of the bandwidth of reading.

Is there any problem with my measurement method? Is the bandwidth difference between reading and writing really that huge?

Code:

```cpp
asm (R"(
.bss
.align 64
    A: .zero 128 * 1024 * 1024
.text
)");
void read() {
    asm volatile (R"(
.intel_syntax noprefix

lea rdi, A[rip]
lea rsi, [rdi + 128 * 1024 * 1024]
.align 64
1:
    add eax, [rdi + 64 * 0]
    add ebx, [rdi + 64 * 1]
    add ecx, [rdi + 64 * 2]
    add edx, [rdi + 64 * 3]
    add eax, [rdi + 64 * 4]
    add ebx, [rdi + 64 * 5]
    add ecx, [rdi + 64 * 6]
    add edx, [rdi + 64 * 7]
    add rdi, 64 * 8
    cmp rdi, rsi
    jne 1b

.att_syntax
)"::: "rdi", "rsi", "eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx"
    );
}
void write() {
    asm volatile (R"(
.intel_syntax noprefix

lea rdi, A[rip]
lea rsi, [rdi + 128 * 1024 * 1024]
.align 64
1:
    mov [rdi + 64 * 0], al
    mov [rdi + 64 * 1], eax
    mov [rdi + 64 * 2], eax
    mov [rdi + 64 * 3], eax
    mov [rdi + 64 * 4], eax
    mov [rdi + 64 * 5], eax
    mov [rdi + 64 * 6], eax
    mov [rdi + 64 * 7], eax
    add rdi, 64 * 8
    cmp rdi, rsi
    jne 1b

.att_syntax
)"::: "rdi", "rsi"
    );
}

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void measure(const char* name, void (*f)()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) f();
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) f();
    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << name << ": " << (end - start).count() * 1e-6 << " ms" << endl;
}
int main() {
    measure("reading", read);
    measure("writing", write);
}
```

My output:

```
reading: 113.529 ms
writing: 2254.57 ms
```

Comment: You do warm-up runs, so you're not measuring page-fault times, good.  But your read-only run happens while the memory is still unwritten, so all pages can be copy-on-write mapped to the same physical page of zeros.  You'll get L1d hits even if you get some dTLB misses!  (Or at least L3 hits if it uses a 2M hugepage.)  [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) / [Why is iterating though \`std::vector\` faster than iterating though \`std::array\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57130924)

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate since copy-on-write mapping to the same physical page of zeros was only one of multiple problems with the benchmarking methods in std::vector Q&A.  But my answer there goes into that in quite a bit of detail.  If anyone wants to write a newer answer, we can reopen this, but I think probably reasonable to close this.  Trying the benchmarks in the other order would have changed the results, as suggested in the "idiomatic" benchmark-methodology Q&A; that's a good way to check your assumptions and detect methodology problems.

Comment: Also BTW, performance counters should confirm that you're *not* reading DRAM, like `perf stat -M L3_Cache_Fill_BW` to see L3 *miss* bandwidth, or `-M tma_info_system_dram_bw_use`.  [How to calculate the L3 cache bandwidth by using the performance counters linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72597540)